Live Activity is still running after iPhone is rebooted
My app is utilizing ActivityKit to provide a simple start time and runtime for a user timing their live poker session. It runs in the background just fine, and if the app is terminated the Live Activity ends, which is fine, the counter is still being tracked inside the app elsewhere.
The issue is that if the phone is rebooted while the Live Activity is active, it remains active when the phone is turned back on and this is causing all sorts of problems when the app gets reopened. I'd like for the Live Activity to just be killed in the event of a phone reboot or battery dying. How is this handled properly? Below is part of my relevant code for the TimerViewModel class.
class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {

private var timer: Timer?

@Published var liveSessionStartTime: Date?
@Published var liveSessionTimer: String = "00:00"
@Published var activity: Activity<LiveSessionWidgetAttributes>? = nil
@Published var reBuyAmount: String = ""
@Published var initialBuyInAmount: String = ""
@Published var totalRebuys: [Int] = []

var totalBuyInForLiveSession: Int {
    (Int(initialBuyInAmount) ?? 0) + rebuyTotalForSession
}

var rebuyTotalForSession: Int {
    return totalRebuys.reduce(0,+)
}

static var isCounting: Bool {
    UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "liveSessionStartTime") != nil
}

init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidResume), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillTerminate), name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil)
    
    // Attempt to recover liveSessionStartTime from UserDefaults
    guard let startTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "liveSessionStartTime") as? Date else {
        print("No Live Session start time found.")
        return
    }
    liveSessionStartTime = startTime
    updateElapsedTime()
    startUpdatingTimer()
    
    initialBuyInAmount = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "initialBuyInAmount") ?? ""
    totalRebuys = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "totalRebuys") as? [Int] ?? []
}



func startSession() {
    let now = Date()
    liveSessionStartTime = now
    UserDefaults.standard.set(now, forKey: "liveSessionStartTime")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(initialBuyInAmount, forKey: "initialBuyInAmount")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(totalRebuys, forKey: "totalRebuys")
    startUpdatingTimer()
    scheduleUserNotification()
    
    if ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled {
        
        let attributes = LiveSessionWidgetAttributes(eventDescription: "Live Session")
        let state = LiveSessionWidgetAttributes.TimerStatus(startTime: now, elapsedTime: self.liveSessionTimer)
        
        do {
            activity = try Activity<LiveSessionWidgetAttributes>.request(attributes: attributes, 
                                                                         content: .init(state: state, staleDate: nil),
                                                                         pushType: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

}
When the user manually stops the session and ends the timer, this is the code that's called to end the activity, which is working.
func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "liveSessionStartTime")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "initialBuyInAmount")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "totalRebuys")
    
    // End Activity
    Task {
        await Activity<LiveSessionWidgetAttributes>.activities.first?.end(activity?.content, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
    }
    
    cancelUserNotifications()
}

And finally, this snippet is what I thought would be able to handle the phone being rebooted in the event the app is terminated. However that doesn't seem to be the case.
func endActivityKit() {
    
    print("Ending Live Activities")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    Task {
        for activity in Activity<LiveSessionWidgetAttributes>.activities {
            print("Ending Live Activity: \(activity.id)")
            await activity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
}

@objc func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Application will terminate...")
    endActivityKit()
}


applicationWillTerminate is typically never called, so it's not surprising that your dependency upon it does nothing for you.

Rather than trying to figure out if the device has been restarted (which will be hard to do reliably, especially while complying with the AppStore's privacy restrictions), I'd update my app-side code to fix its reliance on the live activity being the source of truth. The source of truth should be your app-side models, which should update/dismiss the live activity it it exists upon launching the app. With the right architecture, an outdated live activity being alive should not cause any issues for your app's logic.

Thanks so much Dávid. Would you mind elaborating / nudging me in the right direction? I still have a ton more to learn with iOS app architecture. Should the timer not have its own class?
